# 3 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. Try adding the missing arguments. Parameters are not defined

Tags: flutter

I am very new to Dart. I have produced this code after watching tutorials on YouTube. For the most part I have been able to troubleshoot most of my problems on my own, yet I cannot figure out my most recent errors. I'm trying to access properties from class Tile than return Tile(with imageAssetPath, selected parent) to my list.generate. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have left the code, which I believe is necessary, down below. Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxVVR.png)

Comment: copy and paste the code here as code. Also, rearrange the question, it is difficult to understand.

Comment: You need to share the snippet of list generation and your mode class in this case

Comment: at lease send the screenshow of the error

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `TileModel()` constructor, you should pass 2 positional argument. If you use 'TileModel.empty()' You can "forget" parameters as they have default values.